# How can I change the format of a DateTime value?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, type-conversion

Using C#/.NET I am trying to convert the datetime format.
I am receiving `03/10/2017` (MM/dd/yyyy) dateTime in this format. I want to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

```
string fromdate = from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
string format1 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate, format1, new CultureInfo("sv-se"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

This is what I tried. `fromdate` is the format that I want but when I try to convert the `string` into `dateTime` format it return me the same format (MM/DD/YYY) that I am trying to run from.

Comment: So if this is C#, why have you tagged it VB.NET and included that in your title?  Do you realize they are not the same thing?

Comment: Your question body says "C#" but the title and tags say `vb.net`?

Comment: Also, a `DateTime` *object* does not have a "format". Formats are for a *string representation* you get from `ToString`.

Comment: How are you viewing the date?  That's what you need to change to make it format it the way you want.

Comment: What is `from`? Please post an example that actually reproduces the issue. The only built-in types that understand the `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` format are DateTime and DateTimeOffset. In this case though, you wouldn't need to parse anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavo the **from** is in date type format

Comment: @Ali then all this code is useless, unless it's a convoluted way to trim milliseconds. You *already* have a DateTime, why go through strings to get back the same value? There are dozens of duplicate questions, where the answer is *"But there's no format to change"*

Comment: @Ali you confuse the DateTime value with how your debugger or application formats that value for display. If you want the DateTime value to be displayed in a certain way, use the formatting features of whatever you use for display. You can change the application's culture. You can specify a format string on most data-bound controls. You can specify both a format string *and* language in reporting applications like Reporting Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... but when I try to convert the string into dateTime format it return me the same format (MM/DD/YYY) that I am trying to run from.
>
> *in reference to*
>
> ```
> string fromdate = from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
> ```

My assumptions are:

1. `from` is actually a `string` instance and you are trying to treat it like it's a `DateTime` and using a format string for `DateTime` (*and then expecting it to be formatted*). When passing a format string to a `string` instance the format will be ignored and the original `string` will be returned which is why you are not seeing any change.
2. You are actually using `string.Format` in your real code like so (*note that if this were not the case you would get a compile error with `fromdate.ToString` OR if `fromdate` was a `DateTime` instance your code would work and you would not have been asking this question*)

   ```
   var fromdate = "03/10/2017";
   var fromdateStr = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", fromdate);
   Console.WriteLine(fromdateStr); // output "03/10/2017"
   ```

To fix this convert `from` to a `DateTime` first using `Parse` or `ParseExact`. Ideally this part of your code would not even allow `from` to be a string, it should be a `DateTime` instance. The rule should be this when looking at your stack.

- Coming **from** the presentation layer (input): Convert to the correct type as **early** as possible.
- Going from the store back **to** the presentation (input) layer: Convert to a string representation (for viewing) as **late** as possible

Even better is to let bound control(s) handle this for you but that depends entirely on what your presentation layer is.

Comment: the **from** is coming as input to the function in **DATETIME** format. All I want is to have my **from** in the **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** in this format and of type **DATETIME**. right now its in MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @Ali then the question makes no sense at all. DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. At best, you'll get back exactly the same value, just with milliseconds trimmed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I figured that out. I made changes to my existing code and it worked with input that I was getting. Thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what "from" is in your code. So I'm just going to assume that this is a random object that has a date in it. In which case, you can do the following

```
var from = DateTime.Now; //We don't know what this is so let's set it as var
DateTime dteFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(from); //Let's convert this to an actual date so we can convert it to a formatted string

string fromdate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", dteFrom);
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this code so it might not be the most "optimal" way of doing it nor might it work correctly but it should give you a great indication of how to go about it.

Comment: from is in dateTime format.  I am getting the from in this format: "MM/DD/YYYY". I want to convert this into YYYY-MM-dd type format.
When I convert the from into string it gets converted in the format that I want but when I try to convert it from STRING to DATETIME format it results again "MM/DD/YYYY in this form